# .bash_profile has to be resourced every time

Tags: drush, 8

I installed Drush 8.0.0 for Drupal 8 on Linux Mint 17.1 via Composer.

I added Composer's directory to .bash_profile.

```
export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

The problem is that every time I want to run Drush now, I have to re-source .bash_profile with `source ~/.bash_profile`.

Otherwise, I get an error saying it is not installed.

> The program 'drush' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: sudo apt-get install drush

How can I keep it sourced?

Comment: This should explain it http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=158113

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put these commands in your ~/.bashrc file, which is sourced every time a new shell is started.

You might also want to try the new `drush init` command, which should do this setup for you.  Be sure that you are using Drush 8.0.1 or later.